# undefined method mysqli_ssl_set

Tags: methods, mysqli, undefined

I am having a problem, I am trying to write some code listed below in php;

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['reg00'] != "yes")
    {
    header ('Location: https://somewebsite.ca/nodirect.html');
    exit();
    }
$EmailAddress = $_POST["EmailAddress"];
$_SESSION['reg01'] = "yes";
if (!$EmailAddress)
    {
    die ('All fields are required');
    }
if (!filter_var($EmailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    die ('Please verify you have included the correct email address');
    }
$db = mysqli_init();
$db->mysqli_ssl_set($db, 'C:\apache\apache\conf\00key.pem', 'C:\apache\apache\conf\00cert.pem', NULL, NULL, NULL);
// $db->mysqli_real_connect($db, 'localhost', 'User', 'Password', 'ibank', MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);

// $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'User', 'Password', 'ibank');
// $get = $db->prepare('SELECT EmailAddress FROM accounts WHERE EmailAddress = ?');
// $get->bind_param('s', $EmailAddress);
// $get->execute();
// $result = $get->get_result();
// if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    // {
    // die ('Email Address exists already');
    // }
$db->close();
// mysqli_close($con);
session_write_close();
```

?>

The line I am specifically having trouble with is "$db->mysqli_ssl_set" everytime I run it I get undefined method, I have altered everything I can think of, did a thorough search on both Google and Stackoverflow and was unable to find any similar problems with a solution, can you please help me.

P.S. User and Password are not my credentials, I have not included my true credentials, LOL, I am using Apache 2.4.4, PHP 5.4.14 and MySQL 5.6.11 Community Version on Windows 7.  I created the encryption keys myself using OpenSSL 1.0.1e.

To give a quick rundown of what I am trying to do, I am trying encrypt my connection between PHP and MySQL using my account which is set up for 256 bit enryption on MySQL.  I am not even 100% whether or not I am going about it the right method.  I originally had a standard account set up in MySQL and was able to connect to that with no problems.

I am also using the encryption key and certificate created for my website, can I do that, or do I have to create some specifically for PHP.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

I am ignoring some lines with a // because I am only uncommenting the lines if I know everything else is working, to help me narrow down exactly which line is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$db->mysqli_ssl_set` should be `$db->ssl_set`

Comment: why thank you, you are a genius so simple yet complex, LOL, works perfect now, thank you.